# Compatibility of Asus phone with US local sim

Tags: usa, online-resources, cellphones, communication

I will be traveling to Ohio, USA in the first week of June. I am not sure whether the internet roaming packages in airtel or matrix sim work there. So I prefer to take local carriers of the United States such as AT&T, Virgin, Sprint.

But I want to know whether my phone will be compatible with the sim. My model is ASUS ZENFONE MAX PRO M1. Can anybody please help me to find it out?

---

Okay. I have a Samsung tab. The following link gives the the exact model.

https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-tab-t355y-16-gb-8-inch-wi-fi-4g-tablet-smoky-titanium/p/itmegqbfpvpbpreg?pid=TABEAZYWQNUYMJBW&srno=b_1_9&otracker=browse&lid=LSTTABEAZYWQNUYMJBWXJI2FU&fm=organic&iid=2a180633-427e-48b3-8a40-f099ba7ba71a.TABEAZYWQNUYMJBW.SEARCH&ppt=CLP&ppn=CLP%3Atablets-store&ssid=tq4376yycr12vhfk1558411162588.

Can anybody help me to find out whether this will work in Ohio area with a US local sim.

Comment: I am currently in India. I bought this phone from India. Actually Asus is a Taiwanese company.

Comment: This model phone came with two different radios, depending on which region of the world it was sold in. Both work in the US but only one gets 4G LTE in the US. I'm trying to figure out how to tell which model you have, and I'll post an answer once I have done.

Comment: Well...where did you (the OP) buy the Asus phone?

Comment: I don't know what is meant by OP. I bought my Asus phone in India via Flipkart.

Comment: OP means "original poster" and refers to you here, or whoever posted something starting a thread in forums or a question here on Stack Exchange. It's a commonly used abbreviation on the Internet worth remembering.

Comment: As for the current question: we are not doing your research. I have added the online-resources tag and answered in a way that is useful for everyone else because that's what this site is about. But using the resources I linked for you, that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many sites to do this. https://willmyphonework.net/ is very often linked but it seems your phone is not found by them (or I might've missed it). https://www.frequencycheck.com/search?s=+ASUS+ZENFONE+MAX+PRO+M1 seems to list ... all of them. This points out a different problem: a marketing name like this often tells you little and you need to know a lot more. This site lists *eight* different models. Your "about phone" screen and if that's still not enough, then [xda forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/) are the best bet in figuring this out.

To add to the merriment, there are many LTE bands used by a carrier and if a frequency check says some but not all bands are supported then you will have no idea whether the place where you go to will have coverage or not because not all bands are used everywhere...

Comment: Thanks for your last comment. I could not understand through the online resources you have provided. It is because of my limited knowledge in all these. That is why I again added the question. Not for anybody to do a research for me.  Please help me to delete my entire question. I tried but I could not.